# Application insights imprecise client location

Tags: javascript, azure-application-insights

User is accessing from city Trieste, Application Insights shows it as Treviso.

I use javascript API to get the Page View from my client.

how do I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a mobile user, or broadband user? If the latter, probably it's related to how their ISP routes their requests and where its gateway is - you often don't see the original IP of the user's connection, you just get the IP of where it exited the ISP network. Not sure this would be related to applicationinsights specifically.

Comment: The IP location database we use is out of date. This is a know issue for us and we’re working on getting it updated.

Comment: in my case user are from broadband, is there anything I can do to resolve this issue?